# Android NDK: unable load arm64-v8a on 64bit device

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

My app run perfectly on 32bit android devices when I try to run on 64bit devices 
its gives me error on build time.

**Error:**

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process D:\Software\sdk\NDK\android-ndk-r17\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=E:\Projects\TestProjects\VirtualApp-master\VirtualApp\lib\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=E:\Projects\TestProjects\VirtualApp-master\VirtualApp\lib\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=E:/Projects/TestProjects/VirtualApp-master/VirtualApp/lib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=E:\Projects\TestProjects\VirtualApp-master\VirtualApp\lib\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib E:/Projects/TestProjects/VirtualApp-master/VirtualApp/lib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libva++.so}
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_STL gnustl_static is deprecated and will be removed in the next release. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    
Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: :E:/Projects/TestProjects/VirtualApp-master/VirtualApp/lib/src/main/jni    
Android NDK: WARNING:E:/Projects/TestProjects/VirtualApp-master/VirtualApp/lib/src/main/jni/fb/Android.mk:fb: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : va++ <= IOUniformer.cpp
E:/Projects/TestProjects/VirtualApp-master/VirtualApp/lib/src/main/jni/Foundation/IOUniformer.cpp:130:23: error: use of undeclared identifier '__NR_chmod'
    int ret = syscall(__NR_chmod, redirect_path, mode);
                      ^
E:/Projects/TestProjects/VirtualApp-master/VirtualApp/lib/src/main/jni/Foundation/IOUniformer.cpp:140:23: error: use of undeclared identifier '__NR_fstatat64'
    int ret = syscall(__NR_fstatat64, dirfd, redirect_path, buf, flags);
                      ^
E:/Projects/TestProjects/VirtualApp-master/VirtualApp/lib/src/main/jni/Foundation/IOUniformer.cpp:149:23: error: use of undeclared identifier '__NR_fstatat64'
    int ret = syscall(__NR_fstatat64, dirfd, redirect_path, buf, flags);
                      ^
E:/Projects/TestProjects/VirtualApp-master/VirtualApp/lib/src/main/jni/Foundation/IOUniformer.cpp:159:23: error: use of undeclared identifier '__NR_fstat64'
    int ret = syscall(__NR_fstat64, redirect_path, buf);
                      ^
```

....
....
...
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    make: *** [E:/Projects/TestProjects/VirtualApp-master/VirtualApp/lib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/va++/Foundation/IOUniformer.o] Error 1

I have build app on 64bit device using following steps.

1. Add "arm64-v8a" in abiFilters
2. update APP_ABI in Application.mk

but 
**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MAIN_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := va++


LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wno-error=format-security -fpermissive -DLOG_TAG=\"VA++\"
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(MAIN_LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(MAIN_LOCAL_PATH)/Foundation
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(MAIN_LOCAL_PATH)/Jni



LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Jni/VAJni.cpp \
                   Foundation/IOUniformer.cpp \
                   Foundation/VMPatch.cpp \
                   Foundation/SymbolFinder.cpp \
                   Foundation/Path.cpp \
                   Foundation/SandboxFs.cpp \
                   Substrate/hde64.c \
                   Substrate/SubstrateDebug.cpp \
                   Substrate/SubstrateHook.cpp \
                   Substrate/SubstratePosixMemory.cpp \

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -latomic
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := fb

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(MAIN_LOCAL_PATH)/fb/Android.mk

LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS := true
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_ABI :=  arm64-v8a
APP_PLATFORM := android-24
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_OPTIM := release
VA_ROOT          := $(call my-dir)
NDK_MODULE_PATH  := $(NDK_MODULE_PATH):$(VA_ROOT)
```

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"



        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86","arm64-v8a"

            }

        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path file("src/main/jni/Android.mk")
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        //IJobService need NewApi
        warning 'NewApi','OnClick'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Comment: Does it compile if you use another version of NDK?

Comment: @geisshirt No,  I have compiled this in latest and older versions of NDK but still facing same error...

Comment: `Application.mk` only has one architecture (`APP_ABI`) while your gradle file has three (`abiFilters`).

Comment: @geisshirt APP_ABI in Application.mk is ignored when built through gradle.

Comment: Try to insert `#include <sys/syscall.h>` early in `IOUniformer.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

[CXX1405] error when building with ndkBuild using C:\Users\IT RENTAL\AndroidStudioProjects\appcloner\lib\src\main\jni\Android.mk: Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\IT RENTAL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\IT RENTAL\AndroidStudioProjects\appcloner\lib\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\IT RENTAL\AndroidStudioProjects\appcloner\lib\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:\Users\IT RENTAL\AndroidStudioProjects\appcloner\lib\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\591uu4n4/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\IT RENTAL\AndroidStudioProjects\appcloner\lib\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\591uu4n4/lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

'C:\Users\IT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

any idea on this issue ?

Comment: Please post it as a separate question and share the link in comment to this question.
ndk-build however should run with full ndk path and you must reside "cd ProjectPath/"
then run ndk-build clean

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31810277)